# How to use dplyr group_by and get indices each distinct grouping?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can we use `dplyr` `group_by` then assign an indices to each unique grouping, before returning the original data.frame with the grouping indices?

#### Example

```
df <- data.frame(
  user=c("Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Paul", "Paul", "Mary", "Mary", "Mary"),
  purchase=c("Snickers", "Snickers", "Coke", "Pepsi", "Pepsi", "Snickers", "Pepsi", "Coke"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

This works, but only because I manually hard coded the answers i.e. `c(1,2,1,1,2,3)`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(user, purchase) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  cbind(., c(1,2,1,1,2,3)) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by=(c("user", "purchase")))

   user purchase ...3
1 Peter Snickers    1
2 Peter Snickers    1
3 Peter     Coke    2
4  Paul    Pepsi    1
5  Paul    Pepsi    1
6  Mary Snickers    1
7  Mary    Pepsi    2
8  Mary     Coke    3
```

How can we `group_by`, assign an indicies to each distinct group, before ungrouping so that the indices return as an additional column to the original data.frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(user) %>%
 mutate(indices = cumsum(!duplicated(purchase)))

  user  purchase indices
  <chr> <chr>      <int>
1 Peter Snickers       1
2 Peter Snickers       1
3 Peter Coke           2
4 Paul  Pepsi          1
5 Paul  Pepsi          1
6 Mary  Snickers       1
7 Mary  Pepsi          2
8 Mary  Coke           3
```

Answer (score 1):

can still be done in this way

```
df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  right_join(df)

 user  purchase index
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 Peter Snickers     1
2 Peter Snickers     1
3 Peter Coke         2
4 Paul  Pepsi        1
5 Paul  Pepsi        1
6 Mary  Snickers     1
7 Mary  Pepsi        2
8 Mary  Coke         3
```